# How to run Windows Mobile application in full screen mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, compact-framework, fullscreen

I have a Windows Mobile application developed with Visual Studio 2010 and C# (Smart Device Project). When I run the application there's a start menu bar visible on the top and keyboard bar on the bottom. How can I make my application run in full-screen mode?

If possible I would like to have a solution that will allow me to turn full-screen mode on and off on runtime (after clicking some form button for example).

Comment: As far as I know VS2010 doesn't support Windows Mobile development. So is this a Windows Phone project or do you use VS2008 or am I wrong?

Comment: He said "Smart Device Project" so it's not going to be Windows Phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a mobile application stay on top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747615/how-to-make-a-mobile-application-stay-on-top)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639614/start-bar-shows-up-over-maximized-form-pocket-pc-2003

Comment: @Dmcf: Are you, perhaps, developing under Visual Studio **2008**?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming the question is about Windows Mobile and not Windows Phone.)

On Windows Mobile if you want to hide parts of Windows that normally can't be hidden, you have to hide them with P/Invoke. There are plenty of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472630/disable-menu-bar-in-windows-mobile-6-5) like this already answered and some [other resources](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128737/Mobile-Development-Disable-Windows-Mobile-6-5-Star) too. And of course you can call the P/Invoke from an event handler.