# Hide Title Bar in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am working in a Windows mobile project.
Due to some project requirement I need to Hide the form's tittle bar, but didn't find any properties of the form to do so.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable menu bar in Windows Mobile 6.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472630/disable-menu-bar-in-windows-mobile-6-5)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747615/how-to-make-a-mobile-application-stay-on-top

Comment: Also note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639614/start-bar-shows-up-over-maximized-form-pocket-pc-2003

Answer (score 1):

to hide the forms title bar you have to use

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

if you like to hide the menu bar too, use

```
this.Menu = null;
```

[image]   [image]   [image]

In general a Windows Mobile Form does not have a caption but the form's title (caption text) appears as part of the top bar.

~josef

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using Winforms using WPF you can try consider this:-

```
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = string.Empty;
```

Otherwise, you could set FormBorderStyle to None.

or you can try this:-

```
this.ShowInTaskBar = false;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, this is not a WPF project. It is a Windows Mobile project in Compact Framework.

Comment: Have you considered the second option?

Comment: Second option doesn't exist in CF either

Answer (score 0):

I haven't developed for WindowsMobile, but I have for Windows CE. In Windows CE, I would do the following to hide the Window Title Bar.

1. FormBorderStyle set to None
2. ControlBox - False
3. MinimizeBox - False
4. MaximizeBox - False

Try that

Comment: @JhonBoston Try hiding the HHTaskBar window if it exits.. you have to p/invoke FindWindow and hide it (google it, plenty of examples). That would be my next try

Answer (score 0):

For window CE devices you can try these properties to hide title bar.

**TopMost ====> TRUE**

**WindowState =====> Normal**

**FormBorderStyle ====> None**

hope it will help you... :)